# How would I add a unetbootin entry to grub?

Tags: unetbootin

I know how to add entries, just need to know the entry code.

Thanks

Comment: You're on the wrong path trying to use unetbootin for this purpose. GRUB can already boot a .iso image: See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot .  Unetbootin is NOT an installer - it merely simplifies the steps to make a USB bootable.

Comment: UNetbootin boots using Syslinux, not GRUB. The Boot menu is syslinux.cfg and is similar to the GRUB boot menu grub.cfg. UNetbootin was last updated August 25, 2021.